# How to filtering message with AWS SNS with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I'm using 'aws-sdk' gem.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby

Using below gem

```
'aws-sdk (1.11.0)'
```

I want to use filtering messages function.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering.html

I understood I should set Filter policy.

but, I could not find how to set it.

I have read below.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/sns-examples.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/index.html

How can I use this function?

Thank you.

Comment: Does the following help? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/SNS/Client.html#set_topic_attributes-instance_method

Comment: @rantingsonrails thank you for your advice.
thank you for your advice.
I checked 'set_topic_attributes' and 'set_subscription_attributes'.
but, There is no description about 'FilterPolicy'.

According to the CLI example, setting of FilterPolicy seems to be done for subscription.
```
aws sns set-subscription-attributes \
  --subscription-arn arn:aws:sns:ap-northeast-1:123456789012:Insurance-Quote-Requests:20ae8621-e33b-4a6e-952c-62fa92bac171 \
  --attribute-name FilterPolicy \
  --attribute-value '{"insurance_type":["car", "boat"]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I could set FilterPolicy using set_subscription_attributes.
DeliveryPolicy and RawMessageDelivery were valid attribute names in the description of this page, and FilterPolicy could be used too.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/SNS/Client.html#set_subscription_attributes-instance_method

```
params = {subscription_arn: subscription_arn, attribute_name: 'FilterPolicy', attribute_value: '{"event_type": ["order_placed", "order_cancelled"]}'}
client.set_subscription_attributes(params)
```